# How can I post my data to php without loading another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am having trouble trying to send data to a php page without leaving the current page and if successful, content of the external php page which is loaded from database is displayed. I have included my current codes below. Please everyone I need help and I will be thankful.

```html
<form class="myform">
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="a" id="x" required ></input>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="a" id="y" required></input>
   <button class="b" id="n">Submit</button>
</form>
 
<div id="display"></div>
```

And here is my javascript below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("button#n").click(function() {
  
     var $username = $('input#x').val();
     var $password = $('input#y').val();
  var $mydata = $('.myform').serialize();
     
  if ($username != "" && $password != "") {
   
            $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/products/s1.php'
       type: 'POST',
          data: $mydata,
    dataType: 'text',
          success: function(data) {
   
           $("#display").html(data);
          }
  });
        }   
 });
});
           
  });
});
```

And here is the content of the php page Iam posting to`

```html
<?php
 require_once("data-var.php");

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 echo "Failed to connect to database: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, password from Administrator WHERE password = (?)"))) {
 echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $password)) {
 echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
 echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->store_result()) {
 echo "Failed to store result: (" .$stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "welcome";
} else {
 echo 0;
}

// free result
$stmt->free_result();

// close statement
$stmt->close();

// close connection
$mysqli->close();

?>v
```

`

Comment: You need to prevent the default browser form submit process or page will reload

Comment: When I used the attributes "method" and "action" with their values, the page redirected to the php page,  later,  I removed the attributes and it didn't redirect and the console is not showing any error I am still in wonder

Comment: The variables $username and $password are here only for checking that inputs are not empty.

Comment: The main data to send is in $mydata which is a serialized form data

Comment: Still need to prevent default. If no `action` will submit to same page causing reload  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: thank you very much.  you helped me to figure sth out. what I did last I removed method" and "post" attributes from the form and removed the submit button from the  form and pasted it outside the form, it looked as though nothing was happening but when I inspected on Firefox,  I noticed that the request was successful and I saw the response in console.  Here there is still a problem as I want to display the response on same page inside "#display" . Please any suggestions thanks again.

Comment: code you have in success handler should do what you want ... `$("#display").html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

With in the ajax request data set as an object like this

```
data: {my data:$mydata,password:$password},
```

Also there is many other issues with your code

Comment: Thank you so much @Osama your answer was helpful to me. But still I'm having trouble displaying the response on the page.  Any solution. Thanks.

Comment: I will be happy to help you , in the success loop through the data with foreach for loop and do your work any help send your code

Comment: my javascript code has changed over time and here is what I use so far $('button#n').click(function() {
 
 var $username = $('input#x').val();
 var $password = $('input#y').val();
 
 if ($username != "" && $password != "") {
  
  
  $.post( 'http://localhost/products/s1.php',
      $('.myform').serialize(),
      function(data) {
       $('div#display').html(data);
    $('p').text("WELCOME");
    
      }
  );
 } 
 
});

Comment: You use html(data) to display result ?

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to do but can't still see the response on the specified div element, not even anywhere on the page.

Comment: Try to console.log(data) to see if it is printed in console and in which way

Comment: the fact is when I inspected, I found out that the request returned status code 200 and I went ahead to check the response text in the console, I saw  the integer 0, since I passed a wrong password. I later included error parameter like this: error: function(){$(#display).html("Error");} , This is when I saw the Text "Error" printed inside the div#display on the page. How do I fix this.

Comment: In your php try to set $password as a variable which return True result from the database table without used post if it work good then the error from your ajax request else the error will be In the php code itself

Comment: I think also that your php code return many values as more than one if come true and echo somthing try to use else if and also define a variable for example $html and echo once at the end of php code